# Extracting specific OpenStreetMap tags in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, attribute-table, missing-data, arcgis-editor-osm

The purpose of my research is to look into public ITS (Intelligent Transport System). To do this in a realistic way I need not only the city map but also the public transport routes.

I work with ArcMap 10.3. As input data an OSM file, I use ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap to import it.

I have the list of points , lines and polygones but in attribute table most of information are missing (e.g., public route numbers, directions and operation time)

How can I extract the missing information?

Comment: Please rephrase your question to something like "how to extract specific OSM tags in ArcGIS". I suggest you take a look at the ArcGIS OSM Editor (https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=75716d933f1c40a784243198e0dc11a1) which allows you to select the tags you want. It take a while to get a hang of it but it works

Comment: You can pre process your input with [osmconvert](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert)